# I have ul that has its li elements on one line. Can i make it responsive?

Tags: html, css, html-lists, responsive

I have an `ul` containing my credit card icons. I have used `background-image` and `display:inline` for the LIs and they appear nicely on a big screen.

However, on mobile, the icons get cut off. So my question is can I either make them appear on two lines on mobile or maybe just scale down the size. I tried `transform:scale` for `max-width:474px` and it does work but it pushes all the icons to the right, and even if I add `float:left` or `text-align:left`, nothing changes.

Here's the code:

```css
.payment-methods {
  float: left;
  white-space: nowrap;
  list-style-position: outside;
  list-style-type: disc;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

.payment-methods li {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: auto auto;
  display: inline;
  padding: 10px 40px;
}

.payment-methods .visa {
  background-image: url("https://via.placeholder.com/40x20");
}

.payment-methods .mastercard-card {
  background-image: url("https://via.placeholder.com/40x20")
}

.payment-methods .american-express-card {
  background-image: url("https://via.placeholder.com/40x20")
}

.payment-methods .discover-card {
  background-image: url("https://via.placeholder.com/40x20")
}

.payment-methods .paypal-card {
  background-image: url("https://via.placeholder.com/40x20")
}
```

```html
<ul class="payment-methods">
  <li class="visa"></li>
  <li class="mastercard-card"></li>
  <li class="american-express-card"></li>
  <li class="discover-card"></li>
  <li class="paypal-card"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Next time please convert your code into a runnable snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing these...

```
.payment-methods {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    padding: 0;
}

.payment-methods li {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: auto auto;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 0;
    height: 20px;
    width: 40px;
}
```

More about [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) and a [flexbox generator](http://the-echoplex.net/flexyboxes/) you can play with.

Comment: EDIT: This works 1000%. I had some css I had previously added that was throwing it off, but it works like a charm. Especially, once I added a width on the ul element for @media screen and (max-width:747px); Thanks for taking the time man!

Comment: It looks like there is a width on the ul? or something that needs adjusted.  You can have flexed elements inside each other so you should be good.  Is there a URL I can look?

Comment: It's all good, you were 100% correct. I had set an max-width: of 200px that I forgot about. I adjusted it and it works great. Now I'm onto adding elements on either side of the using more flexbox :)

Answer (score 0):

You made your elements `inline` and then directed their parent to stop wrapping new lines. If we get rid of the `white-space` directive, `max-width` works as you would expect.

```css
.payment-methods {
  max-width: 200px;
  float: left;
  /*white-space: nowrap; this is the issue */
  list-style-position: outside;
  list-style-type: disc;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

.payment-methods li {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: auto auto;
  display: inline;
  padding: 10px 40px;
}

.payment-methods .visa {
  background-image: url("https://via.placeholder.com/40x20");
}

.payment-methods .mastercard-card {
  background-image: url("https://via.placeholder.com/40x20")
}

.payment-methods .american-express-card {
  background-image: url("https://via.placeholder.com/40x20")
}

.payment-methods .discover-card {
  background-image: url("https://via.placeholder.com/40x20")
}

.payment-methods .paypal-card {
  background-image: url("https://via.placeholder.com/40x20")
}
```

```html
<ul class="payment-methods">
  <li class="visa"></li>
  <li class="mastercard-card"></li>
  <li class="american-express-card"></li>
  <li class="discover-card"></li>
  <li class="paypal-card"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I'll try to figure out the snippet thing next time. I removed the 'white-space:nowrap' ; however nothing changed. using 'width' or 'max-width' doesn't seem to work as well. Instead of 'nowrap' , should there be a different command for the 'white-space' ?

Comment: well, it does work but only on a wider resolution. if you cut the screen down to a mobile width screen, only 3 of the 5 icons are showing even in your snippet. I'd like to either scale them down or make them in two lines for mobile, assuming there would have to be some @media screen and (max-width:474px) css